# Use BaseRichBolt or BaseBasicBolt in case of at-most-once processing

Tags: apache-storm

I'm beginner in Storm and I would like to know whether I should use `BaseRichBolt` or `BaseBasicBolt` if at-most-once processing is good for me?

As I understand in case of `BaseBasicBolt` tuples are automatically anchored and acknowledged and in case of `BaseRichBolt` we have to do that ourselves. Does that mean that I should use `BaseRichBolt` if I want at-most-once processing?

My logic is that anchoring and acking will unnecessary make things slower, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enable fault-tolerance in Storm, it is required that Spouts assign message IDs to the tuples they emit. As long as there are no message IDs assigned, acking and anchoring will have no effect.

Thus, the overhead that `BaseBasicBolt` has is tiny and you should not be able to measure any performance difference. Of course, using `BaseRichBolt` will avoid this tiny overhead at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not worrying about data lost you can use BaseRichBolt but if you want to guaranteed message processing, that time you need to use BaseBasicBolt.In storm three type message processing at least once, exactly once and at-most-once.
Useful link: https://bryantsai.com/fault-tolerant-message-processing-in-storm/

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @nilesh yes its seems user removed his post

Comment: @Nilesh https://bryantsai.com/fault-tolerant-message-processing-in-storm-6b57fd303512